# createPattern method implementation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I'm attempting to draw a filled rectangle that uses a pattern for the fillStyle.
The following code allows one rect to be drawn, but after that, the drawing is thrown off for all subsequent actions.

This is the code that controls the fill:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR4Ag1va1Vm9Tynun8vY89CS1pY1eNMWGMxrc5efOIzEcQ-4IFa'
var pat = context.createPattern(img, 'repeat');
context.fillStyle = pat;
```

I suspect there's something about the createPattern method that I'm missing.
Are there alternatives to what I'm trying to accomplish that don't use createPattern?
I've noticed some examples use onload(); the value for img.src changes in my live environment, so I'm not sure if that would be relevant.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Dvtz3/10/

**ok, so it turns out the chrome security error is fixed once I run live rather than local, but instead of the rect filling in with a pattern, it's filling it solid. The fill patterns are working fine in FF**

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/97446129/2-28/joined%2011-1/filltest.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Viewing the error console, I see it full of `SecurityError`s. This is because when you draw to the canvas, you are tainting it with a cross-origin image. This will disallow you from calling `getImageData` for security reasons, hence the "funky" result.

Comment: the value of img.src is something local like 'images/pattern1.jpg' in the real version. would this still cause a problem?

Comment: I'm afraid I wouldn't know. I would need to see the live version with local image to be sure. But you should check your error console. Is anything showing up?

Comment: It appears you are correct. In firefox this code works fine (allowing the drawing of rects one after another with new fill patterns), but chrome is showing the security error. I guess I need an alternate method for chrome??